# How to sort the cells of a TableViewController based on detailTextLabel.text values?

Tags: ios, sorting, uitableview

I have few cells dynamically added to a TableViewController. Since the cells get added to tableView on the fly I cannot arrange them in ascending order but can only sort them once all the cells have been added.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing the TableView's data into a NSMutableArray.
Then you can use the sorting algorithm of your choice to sort the cells. Finally, take the array and apply it back to the table view! Hope this helped!